# How to print profile targets using ColorSync Utility in Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10)?

Tags: printing, color-management, os-x

I am trying to print a color profiling target (created with Argyll) using the ColorSync Utility in Mac OS X 10.10.

Unfortunately, the option "Print as Color Target" is always greyed out. In some documentation, I found that this option is only enabled if the file to print is somehow designed for the target printer. How can I create such a TIFF file that is accepted to be printed as a profiling target?

I have not found any clue in the Argyll documentation or on Apple sites. Even using Adobe Color Printer Utility is not working, because in the printing dialog there, the ColorSync option is permanently switched on and greyed out, so I can't switch it off to disable color management for the print.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I use is assigning ProPhoto profile to the target and temporary assignment of the same profile as printer profile. In that case colour management does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Adobe Color Printing Utility. The print dialog on my computer looks like so:
[image]

[image]